# 301 redirect to get rid of the slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Is there a way in htaccess to redirect all the pages from / to nothing. So for example i want this

```
http://somesite.com/something/ ==> http://somesite.com/something
http://somesite.com/another_thing/ ==> http://somesite.com/another_thing
http://somesite.com/page3/ ==> http://somesite.com/page3
http://somesite.com/page4/ ==> http://somesite.com/page4
```

page3, page4, something, another_thing are all directories with an index.php file in each... and this is how i handled it

in my htaccess i am getting rid of the / by this

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

I basically want to 301 redirect just for seo reasons so everybody ends up on the non slash pages even if they are cached.thanks in advance

this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove trailing slashes from all requests that have them, try:

```
RewriteRule   ^/(.+)/$  /$1   [R]
```

See as well [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) and look for *Canonical URLs*. Additionally please be aware of the documentation and security warning for the [`DirectorySlash Off` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).

Comment: does that go before of after my htaccess

Comment: It belongs into the same .htaccess file. I would place it before the other rewriteCond/Rule so it's more clear with the following lines.